# How can you move the Ado.net entity database?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

At the moment my application has a database in the installation directory, but I would like to move it to the users local app data folder. How can I do this? CAN you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
File.Move(pathToDatabase,
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        "databaseName.mdf"));
```

but you need to remember to change the connection string for the application as well (wherever you're storing that).

Answer (score 0):

it would be better you mentioned which database technology you use but odds are high you can simply use File.Move. of course dont forget to arrange connection string for new location.